# Assigning Multiple People to Task

Tags: 2013, list, column, tasks

I created a Task app using SP13.  Is there a way to add more than one more person per task without using a workflow?  I have added a Person and Group column; therefore, the end-user can add the person that would be responsible for the task.  However, I am not sure how I can capture more than one person per task.  An idea I had was to create additional Person and Group column therefore the metadata is captured.  Any suggestions?  Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You can use a SharePoint group - Then add multiple users into that group. This way its easier to maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign multiple people in task list, for that you do following.

Go to List settings --> Click on Assigned To column, then Under Allow Multiple selections, select Yes radio button.

If you have built this as an app then you might need to specify in the people picker that multiples are allowed.

Comment: When a task is added to multiple users, who exactly can complete the task out of those users? How do I know which user has completed and who hasnt?